# Facebook - Frictionless requests on android

Tags: android, facebook

Is there a way to tell the facebook android SDK to send frictionless requests on a user->user app request ?

I've integrated an app on android by following the tutorial on the [facebook website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/). There is some documentation on how to send facebook [user->user requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/) using `mFacebook.dialog(context, "apprequests", params, new AppRequestsListener());` , but there is no mention of how to make these requests frictionless. On the web the `frictionlessRequests:true` option [seems to do the trick](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/). I tried setting this as a parameter on the call to `mFacebook.dialog()` (using the params reference), but that did not help. The facebook requests dialog [documentation page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) claims that this feature is available on android. There is no mention anywhere on how to enable it.

> Frictionless Requests are supported with the Javascript SDK on Desktop
>   Canvas and mobile web as well as with the iOS and android SDKs on
>   native mobile apps.

Is there an equivalent call that can be used for android so the user gets to see the 'Don't ask again' (see pic below) option on the request dialog ? Right now the requests dialog is shown every time even if a request was sent previously.

[image: Frictionless requests]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've struggled with the same thing today. I finally found a way that works for me.
I'm using the sdk 3.0.2b, I followed the guide here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/send-requests/

In step 2 the guide suggests the code:

```
private void sendRequestDialog() {
   Bundle params = new Bundle();
   params.putString("message", "Learn how to make your Android apps social");
   WebDialog requestsDialog = (
   ...
```

After a lot of trial and error adding param frictionless=1 worked for me:

```
private void sendRequestDialog() {
   Bundle params = new Bundle();
   params.putString("message", "Learn how to make your Android apps social");

   params.putString("frictionless", "1"); //Turn on frictionless

   WebDialog requestsDialog = (
   ...
```

Comment: Great! Wrote the FB Dev team to add this information to the doc.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it's not possible on Android, because Facebook official doc says "Frictionless Requests are available to games on Facebook.com or on mobile web using the JavaScript SDK"(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/). But I found your solution, and it works like a charm! :)

Comment: Hi @daniel-backman In the newer sdk version on Facebook they replaced the webdialog method with gamerequestcontent. And I am not able to understand how to put frictionless parameter in that. You have any idea about that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use frictionless "parameter" in bundle but parameter "to" should also be provided then it works. Actually I used in both condition and when I am passing "to" parameter then "don't ask again" not showing. But when use with "to" parameter its working.

```
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", msg);
        params.putString("data", json);
        params.putString("title", title);
        params.putString("frictionless", "1");
```

In above code it's not working.
But in below code it's working.

```
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", msg);
        params.putString("data", json);
        params.putString("to", appendedFriendsID);
        params.putString("title", title);
        params.putString("redirect_uri", "");
        params.putString("frictionless", "1");
```